# Reading Abaqus ODB file

Tags: file-read

I want to write a class for reading the odb file from Abaqus. I was told that there is a C++ interface with functions to extract information from the odb file. But I do not find neither
this function nor the documentation about it. Does anybody know where this interface is?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options for reading odb files, python API and C++ API. The python API will be easier to develop because you can read the *.rpy file in your working directory and see what your GUI commands translate to in pythonic terms. Look at the scripting reference manual in the Abaqus documentation.

Comment: 2 online references for scripting application and API: [Scripting Guide](http://mse-license1.mse.drexel.edu:2080/v6.8/books/ker/default.htm) and [API documentaiton](http://mse-license1.mse.drexel.edu:2080/v6.8/books/cmd/default.htm)

Comment: odb_initializeAPI();
odb_String partName("New_Part");
odb_Odb& odb = openOdb("ODBFile.odb");
odb_finalizeAPI();

Comment: but then there were errors with missing inttypes.h and so on. I am working with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. So I suppose that their interface is very old if they need inttypes.h. Am I doing something wrong? I added the include directories and lib directories in Project Properties, but still the linker does not find the lilbraries

Comment: Actually, now even the linker complains: it does not find odb_InitializeAPI and so on, even if I specified the include and directories and inserted all the libs I have in Abaqus directory in linker properties. Does anybody know in which library the odb_InitializeAPI function is?

Comment: HEre is the location from the abaqus documentaton:10.7.2 Link library location


The libraries necessary to link applications that access the C++ interface are located in the following directories:

UNIX

abaqus_dir/exec/lbr

Windows

abaqus_dir\exec\lbr

where abaqus_dir is the name of the directory in which Abaqus is installed.

Comment: On a Win system it will look like this: C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\6.11-2\exec\lbr

Comment: The missing `inttypes.h` error is because you need `#define HKS_NT` at the top of your main file.